# Repeating fields in Django Model Form

Tags: django-models, django-forms, formset

I am using Django 1.11 and I'm hoping to get some advice on the best way to approach designing a form where one to may documents can be included using the following Model:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    document_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    document_class = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=255)
    document_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
```

When the form is displayed in the template, I need the ability to repeat the document_date & document fields based on the user selecting an "add another document" button. The document_class field is not repeated in the form as it is the same for each record of document captured in the model/database.

From what I have been able to gather so far looking into this, using Formset will be the way to achieve this. Before I head down this path can anyone provide advice if this is the best way or if they recommend an alternative? Other considerations appear to be using Model Formset or Inline Formset. Does anyone have any advice if those methods would be more suited? Any guidance on how to approach this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you want to create multiple model with same fields ?

Comment: Hi navyad. Im not sure I understand your question. I dont think that is what I want. I want a form that can accept file upload of one to many document(s) and associated document_date information for each and store to my database/file location.